# datepicker in jade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, node.js, pug

I'm new to Jade and express and need to add datepicker from jquery UI to one of my layered popup.I have tried inline script and header javascript with onload without any luck.

```
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-1.4.4.js')
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-ui.js')
script(type='text/javascript')
   function initDate() {
   $('#mdate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
}

input(type='text', name='mdate', id='mdate')
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You do realize that `$('#mdate')` does not indicate the one with the ___name___ `mdate` right? You would need to set the ___id___ of that element to `mdate` ...

Comment: nope..is there way that I can put this datepicker script below (inpu) line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead

```
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-1.4.4.js')
script(src='/javascripts/jquery-ui.js')
script(type='text/javascript')
   $(function(){
       function initDate() {
          $('#mdate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
       }
   });

input(type='text', name='mdate', id='mdate')
```

All I'm doing is telling the page to wait till it's ready before applying the datepicker

Comment: lol, i cant believe i missed the lack of $(function() {... before.

Comment: I gotta say I still don't like that syntax tho, I prefer `$(document).ready(`

Comment: As do I, but $(function(){ seems to be more widely used anymore, especially in backbone or the likes.